# jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate for list of inserts doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

I'm out of nerves cells and I really need your help guys.

For some reason I can't get list of answers inserted to database

I use jdbcTemplate to do that and my code looks like this

```
public void insertVastaukset(List<Vastaus> vastaukset) {
    final String sql = "insert into vastaus (kysymysID, vastausteksti) values(?,?)";
    getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(sql,
            new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                @Override
                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i)
                        throws SQLException {
                    Vastaus vastaus = vastaukset.get(i);
                    ps.setInt(1, vastaus.getKysymysID());
                    ps.setString(2, vastaus.getVastausteksti());

                }

                @Override
                public int getBatchSize() {
                    return vastaukset.size();
                }
            });}
```

And for some reason the program gives no error! When i tried it couple days ago it gave me null pointer, but now its fixed but still no inserts are created into database. Help me please, Thank you very much!

Comment: Is your transaction set properly. Is it getting committed after the batch update call?

Comment: btw jdbcTemplate.update and query work just fine

Comment: @ManasMarthi I don't know, I'm new to jdbcTemplate, how to check that?. I also tried to display list items in batchUpdate construction and it works, but still no inserts in database

Comment: since update is working fine transaction might be working fine.. batchUpdate returns an int array. try to print the values in it to see what's going on. Look at section 18.4 in spring reference

Comment: I wonder if org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource is a MUST because i have org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource and when i change it to the first one the whole program doest start and give 400 error

Comment: I tried the same batch Update as specified in the spring framework reference (your code is similar). it worked absolutely fine..  And Yes I am using DriverManagerDataSource <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
  <beans:property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
  <beans:property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
  <beans:property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
 </beans:bean>

Comment: @ManasMarhi i use some from ApacheTomcat and when i change it to org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource apache gives me 404 error

Comment: Changed pom dependencies to be able to use org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource. Still getting no insert into database

Comment: Finally its working!!! Thanx everybody for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below catch block to examine the exceptions

```
    int[] updateCounts;
    try {
        updateCounts = getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate("insert into test123 (id, value) values (?,?)",
                new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

                //// YOUR CODE HERE

                });               
    }
     catch (Exception sqle) {
        Throwable s2 = sqle;
        System.out.println("=============v"+s2.getClass().getName()+"=====================");
        while (s2!=null) {
            s2.printStackTrace();
            s2 = s2.getCause();
            if(s2 instanceof java.sql.BatchUpdateException) {
                System.out.println("======================^^^^^^======================");
                ((java.sql.BatchUpdateException) s2).getNextException().printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        throw sqle;
    }
```

Comment: Thank You for answer, ill try it. But I'm pretty sure the problem is because i have bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" instead of org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource, but when i change it project won't run on apache no more. Does anybody have any solution for that?